# If $(1+x+x^2)^n = (p_0+p_1x+p_0x^2+p_3x^3+p_4x^4+\ldots++p_nx^n)$ then prove that $p_1+p4+p7 + \ldots = 3^{n-1}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following questins:  If $(1+x+x^2)^n = (p_0+p_1x+p_0x^2+p_3x^3+p_4x^4+\ldots++p_nx^n)$ then prove that $p_1+p4+p7 + \ldots = 3^{n-1}$

I have  taken x = 1, $\omega$, $\omega^2$ and then sum all the equations. By this, I am able to prove $p+0+p_3+p_6+\ldots=3^{n-1}$. But I cant understand how to prove  $p_1+p4+p7 + \ldots = 3^{n-1}$

Comment: $(1+x+x^2)^n$ is a polynomial of degree $\mathbf{2n}$, **not** $n$

Comment: It's not $p+0$ but $p_0$.

Comment: Are $p4 =p_4$, $p7=p_7$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding sum of expressions involving coefficients of terms in the expansion $(1+x+x^2)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3780014/finding-sum-of-expressions-involving-coefficients-of-terms-in-the-expansion-1) (found using https://approach0.xyz/ formula searching tool.